# Saving a dataframe as a parquet with geometry column

Tags: geometry, pyarrow, aws-data-wrangler

I currently have a column that contains POINT geometry values and using AWS Wrangler I can save it as a CSV, but when I try to save it as a parquet it raises this error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Did not pass numpy.dtype object
```

We are using the latest AWS Wrangler library and an updated pyarrow library (12.0.1) so I am not sure what the issue is, as other people experiencing this issue have said that its because of a previous library version.

Comment: Your question could use more context, but my guess is that you need to use geopandas. geopandas provides a `geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame` class which has a `to_parquet` method for writing to Parquet while preserving geometry.